# Matrices bidimensionales

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar un programa en el cual haga utilización de matrices bidimensionales.

El problema es así: Programa que dé la opción de introducir 5 nombres y 5 tipos de frutas en una matriz bidimensional y al final que aparezca la opción al usuario de elección "¿Qué quieres que te muestre: los nombres o frutas ingresados?" e imprima.
Ya sea opción Switch o con for.

Soy principiante y este es mi planteamiento erróneo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Opt {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [][] matriz= new String [2][5];

        Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Introduzca  nombre");

        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){
            System.out.println (" ");
            for (int j=0; j<=5; j++){
                matriz [i] [j] = scan.NextLine();
            }

            System.out.println ("Introduzca fruta");

            for (int i1=0; i1<=3; i1++){
                System.out.println (" ");
                for (int  j=0; j<=5; j++){
                Object [] frutas;   
                matriz [i] [j]= scan.NextLine;
                System.out.println ("QUE QUIERES QUE TE MUESTRE LOS NOMBRES O FRUTAS INGRESADOS");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Coco,  te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas 

excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!

Comment: ademas de los links que te paso Jorge, veo que pusiste muchas etiquetas, y la unica necesaria aqui es java. aparte de eso, que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: @coco tiene uno errores en tu código  en la linea del for  `for (int i1=0; i1<=3; i1++)` la tiene que colocar asi   `for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) ` mira si puede ser eso el error ademas si te sigue apareciendo edita la pregunta y anexa tu error eso ayuda a que te podamos ayudar mucha mas facil , ademas que tiene un error en en for por que dices que el arreglo es de 2  *5  y  en el for estas haciendo  3 iteraciones  cuando tu  arreglo cuenta solo 2 espacio y igual con el 5

Comment: te dejo una imagen de los areglos para que veas en la parte del for que te esta saliendo mal  ya que se esta debordando por que esta colocando mal las condiciones del for https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/c-arrays.jpg

Answer (score 4):

buenos dias la el codigo tuyo tenia alguno problemas en la parte del for ya que lo tenia mal colocado de la siguiente manera  `for (int i1=0; i1<=3; i1++)` y por eso te puede generar falla al momento de compilar, ademas que tenia las condiciones del arreglo , ya que cuando tiene un arreglo el tamaño del areglo  es la logitud que puede ser un valor    **n** ,pero el tamaño del arreglo es  **n-1** te dejo un una imagen por si tiene dudas puedes consultar  [Documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) de java   sobre el tema

> un tip que puede utilizar para colocoar un for si tiene un arreglo es  [length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000169/getting-the-array-length-of-a-2d-array-in-java) que te ayuda saber el tamaño del  arreglo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Opt {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [][] matriz= new String [2][5];

        Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Introduzca  nombre");

        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            System.out.println (" ");
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                matriz [i] [j] = scan.NextLine();
            }

            System.out.println ("Introduzca fruta");

            for (int i=0; i<2; i1++){// esta mal colocado el for en esta linea   ya que la variable esta acompañada por un numero  
                System.out.println (" ");
                for (int  j=0; j<=5; j++){
                Object [] frutas;   
                matriz [i] [j]= scan.NextLine;
                System.out.println ("QUE QUIERES QUE TE MUESTRE LOS NOMBRES O FRUTAS INGRESADOS");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes una breve explicación de los fallos a la 1º parte de tu problema:

> - Los límites de los bucles *for* sobrepasaban el límite de la matriz.
> - La forma de emplear los bucles tampoco resolvían el problema.

Una forma correcta podría ser:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Opt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [][] matriz= new String [2][5];

        Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                if (i==0){
                     // en la matriz[0][x] van los nombres
                     System.out.println ("Introduzca  nombre: ");
                }else{
                      // en la matriz[1][x] van las frutas
                      System.out.println ("Introduzca fruta: ");
                }
               matriz [i] [j] = scan.nextLine();
            }
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Posible solución (la que yo daría):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] matriz = new String[2][5];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca 5 nombres");

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz[0].length; i++) {
        matriz[0][i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("introduce 5 frutas");

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz[1].length; i++) {
        matriz[1][i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Te muestro los nombres o las frutas?");

    String respuesta = scan.nextLine();

    switch (respuesta) {
    case "nombres":
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matriz[0]));
    case "frutas":
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matriz[1]));
    }
}
```